# How to connect a Mac Book Pro to a LaserWriter II NT

Tags: macbook-pro, printing

I have an Apple [LaserWriter II NT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaserWriter) from the late 80's. Is there a way how I can print to it from my MacBook Pro?

Comment: Looking at the [Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP475?locale=en_US) you'll need a PostScript capable printer driver (which you already have in OS X) and an USB-RS-232 interface.

Answer (score 1):

That machine has an AppleTalk interface - I doubt you'll find anything made in the last 20 years that can connect to it, much less drivers for it that would run under OS X.

12MHz processor & 2MB RAM - I think it's also PostScript only, but I'm not certain.

The Asanté Bridge used to be the thing to connect Ethernet to AppleTalk - but idk if the $60 asking price would be worth it these days - I did find one on Amazon, though - [http://www.amazon.com/Asante-Talk-Ethernet-LocalTalk-Bridge/dp/B00004VUFW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004VUFW)

See also - http://lowendmac.com/network/bridge.shtml

See if a museum would be interested.